# Failure to run the Gulp task runner and error while running Gulp Command

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I inside the folder where the project is located through the command:

```
npm i gulp gulp-sass sass --save-dev
```

I have installed Gulp, but when I want to run it with this command in vs.code terminal :

```
gulp
```

I **get an error**, I wanted to know what caused the error?
On the system node js 14.1.0 & 16.13.0 and npm are already installed

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message hints that `gulp` is not recognized as a command, I don't think this has anything to do with gulp-sass or sass specifically.

#### Option 1

Install [gulp-cli](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-cli) globally:

```
npm i -g gulp-cli
```

glup-cli provides the executable `gulp` command, which will use the version of gulp is installed in your package. This is the preferred way to run gulp.

#### Option 2

Run gulp directly from your node_modules/.bin folder with the `npx` command. npx is set up by npm, so there is no need to install any additional packages.

```
npx gulp
```

or, equivalently

```
npm exec gulp
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it was executed with the second option command

Comment: My question is why, despite the fact that the Node JS and Gulp ( install in local modules folder ) packages are installed, why the ` gulp ` command is not executed ???

Comment: Well, installing a local package is typically not enough to make a command executable. npm can resolve automatically commands inside the scripts of a package.json file, but to make those commands executable from the console, it takes an additional layer. That is why we have global packages like gulp-cli, @vue/cli, @angular/cli, etc.